# How to resolve nuget DLL hell after upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded ASP.NET MVC4 to ASP.NET MVC 5.1 following these [steps from this WebSite](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

I get stuck on upgrading nuget packages, there are plenty of errors and rollsback:

for example

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20710.0' to 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.
WebApi.Core 5.1.0'.
```

or

```
Update-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0' 
to 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.18' failed. Unable to find versions of 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData' that 
are compatible with 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.18'.
```

Is there some easy step to clean and update all and to get rid of this DLL hell?

Comment: I have been there. The only way I got out of the hell you speak of was painful. I'm afraid you already know what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick way to delete all the nuget packages in your project is to manually edit the packages.config file, then delete all the dll references (Only for the dlls in the nuget packages).

This takes a lot less time than uninstalling then all via nuget package manager, especially when there is such a large dependency tree.

Comment: To elaborate on Tom's answer -- the only way I could get the MVC and WebAPI upgrades to work was to find these lines in my packages.config file `<package id="AspNetWebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />` and replace them with `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />`

After that, all I had to do was add a few binding redirects, and I was good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have solved it even if upgrading by nuget command "Update-Package" failed.

1. I have uninstall via nuget all problematic packages and their dependencies for every project.
2. I have setup the same .NET Framework 4.5.1 for all projects in solution (maybe not essential).
3. I have install these packages via nuget one by one.
4. I checked the result by comparing references among project via FindConflictingReferences tool https://gist.github.com/brianlow/1553265 and fixed possible conflicts.

It taked me long time to fix it...